# Why would a javascript function be wrapped as anonymous

Tags: javascript

In reading a technical education post I came across this sample code from the author..sterilized of course. The content of the functions is not what I found curious and everything worked as the author had described.

What caught me was wrapping the function in an anonymous (I think that's what they did) function. The only thing I can see with my meager knowledge is that it creates a grouping/container.

Why is this and should I make a habit of this..I understand the second half may be subjective so disregard if too obtuse.

```
(function ()
{
   FuncName1 = function (var1, var2, var3)
   {
       ....code n stuff....
   }

   FuncName2 = function (var1, var2)
   {
    .....code n stuff...
   }
 })();
```

---

Excellent explanations everyone. Thank You. So my follow on question would be then shouldn't every function be wrapped? For example the author wrapped two functions in one "scope or module". Couldn't those leak into each other?

---

So cookie monster to make the authors code even better I would do as such:

```
(function ()
{
   var FuncName1 = function (var1, var2, var3)
   {
       ....code n stuff....
   }

   var FuncName2 = function (var1, var2)
   {
    .....code n stuff...
   }
 })();
```

The key as you say in your comments is by using the keyword var keeps them in scope of the containing anonymous function. Not using var results in an implicit global scope.

Comment: Given your example, there's no benefit to it since you're creating global variables.

Comment: @cookiemonster lost track in the thread to what your comment was referring to. Are you saying there is no benefit to wrapping each func separately because I'm creating global variables...or are you saying the OP (where both functs are in one anonymous funct) is of no benefit.

Comment: The benefit to using this pattern is to create a variable scope, which offers protection to enclosed variables, and avoids pollution of enclosing variable scopes. Because the `FuncName1/2` variables you created are implicitly global variables, you loose the benefit of the outer `(function() {})();`, so it might as well not be there. Using `var` before your variables creates them in the current function scope, and provides the benefits I described.

Comment: See my latest edits. If it is a repeat of what you have said then good...I understand.

Comment: Yes, looks like you understand.

Comment: For your update, this is where the 'use strict'; comes into play. It will not allow you to implicitly declare variables ie without the var statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the guys said above it creates modular code. If you set the anonymous function to return "things" and you set that to a variable you now have a closure that has name spaced goodness.

```
var name = (function() {

   var 
       lastName = 'Moody',
       firstName = Hank
   ;

   return {
      setName: function(newFirstName, newLastName) { 
                   firstName = newFirstName;
                   lastName = newLastName;
                },
      getName: function() { return firstName + " " + lastName; } 


    }

}());
```

Now you can get and set the code and it lives in it's own scope! Bam - Modular Design Pattern.

```
name.setName('Clark', 'Kent');
console.log(name.getName); // Will now output Clark Kent
```

Very powerful and simple design pattern.

Update:

Almost forgot the most important thing their name - IIFE or immediatetly invoked function expression!

Answer (score 4):

The anonymous function creates a scope. Any definitions inside the anonymous function will not "leak" outside and pollute the global namespace. This lets you write more modular code. When you do need to export something from inside the block into the global namespace, you can do so  explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

"Because variables and functions defined within a function may only be accessed inside, but not outside, that context, invoking a function provides a very easy way to create privacy."

http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Answer (score 3):

This pattern is called 'Module' in Javascript, used for information hiding.

According to the book 'Javascript: The good part'. The correct way of calling should be:

```
(function() {
    ...
}());
```

Not:

```
(function() {
    ...
})();
```

Another method:

```
!function() {
...
}();
```

Comment: Either way is correct, but as in all things there can be a better way to do it... and if Doug Crockford is telling us this is a better way then we should try and follow his lead! All hail Doug!

Comment: @cookiemonster yes, either way is fine. However, I prefer what the book recommends.